# Variable from if statement - jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

Why does console.log() shows A and not B? How do I get it to show B from the variable set in the if statement when the #input changes value?

```
var myNumber = 1;
var myLetter = 'A';

$('button').click(function(){
    if( myNumber == 1 ){
        myLetter = 'B';
    }
});

$('#input').change(function(){
    console.log( myLetter );
});
```

Comment: it show `B` maybe in somewhere it set to `A`

Comment: To show myLetter = 'B' you just need to click a button in the dom. Did you clicked any button? Or find if any where myNumber  or myLetter was changed in you code.

Comment: Your code looks good and the output is also as expected(It shows B when #input changes value). I don't find any issues. Have a look at this working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3qvjdtx/2/